# dispatch_async confliction

Tags: objective-c, ios

Currently i am working on a chatting app, I am trying to upload the image, every thing is working fine except that when image is uploading the UI freeze, so async approach came into the scene, this is what i am trying to do:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; 
        NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

        //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(send:) withObject:imgData waitUntilDone:YES];

        [self send:imgData];
});

}
```

I am getting this error:

> Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread
>   or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a
>   secondary thread. Crashing now...
>
> 1. WebThreadLock
> 2. -[UITextView setText:]
> 3. -[HPTextViewInternal setText:]
> 4. -[HPGrowingTextView setText:]
> 5. -[chatViewController send:]
> 6. __74-[chatViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]_block_invoke_0
> 7. _dispatch_call_block_and_release
> 8. _dispatch_worker_thread2
> 9. _pthread_wqthread
> 10. start_wqthread

I am using HPGrowingTextView to give a iMessage kind of expandable typing area for typing messages, but getting this problem.

I searched this error

> Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread
>   or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a
>   secondary thread

peoples suggests using `performSelectorOnMainThread` but this approach again freeze the UI.

How to solve this conflict or is there any other approach.

```
Inside [self send:imageData]
...building a url and appending hFile(imageData)
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:hFile]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
            [request setHTTPBody:body];

            NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
            NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSString *imgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.www.www/uImages/thumbs/%@",returnString];
...
```

after uploading, thumbnail of image is returned, if I use `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest` I get empty thumbnail which I am diplaying in uitableview.

Comment: what does the [self send:imgData]; does?

Comment: Thanks for reply, its an image uploading method..

Comment: Well you are 100% sure calling the calling the UI from a thread other then the main thread, maybe you have an alert view pop up if the file was uploaded ok ? this is bad, you should execute stuff like that on the main thread

Comment: can you post some of that code? I think you might be handling an interface element of some kind, or a class that does some interface handling.

Comment: image is uploading on web...cant post all the code, please check my post i am editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to change anything in the UI you should do it on the main thread.

So if you want to change the text of `HPGrowingTextView` control you have, you can do the following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    growingTextView.text = @"Some text";
})
```

Comment: but i am not changing the growingTextView text.

Comment: Maybe you're not changing it explicitly, but the method `[HPGrowingTextView setText:]` is certainly called somewhere inside the method `[chatViewController send:]`.

Comment: sorry i forget, actually i am changing the text growingtextview.text=@"" this is to clear it, But now during image upload when I try to type something in it, it again crashed, typing has to do something with main or second thread?

Comment: now i am not getting error on typing or changing text, but when image is uploading and then I try to send text message i am getting this

Comment: -[UIButton bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x863d8d0
2012-08-15 00:37:33.080 TheSendApp[763:15b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x863d8d0'

Comment: It seems a memory issue, make sure the view isn't released.

Comment: Thanks Hejazi and everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the crash because you are calling send outside the main thread.  The stack trace is obvious about this fact.

You need to make those calls on the main thread.  When you do, however, your UI will of course hang because of this call...

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

From the method name, it's obvious that this call is synchronous, and will block until the result is returned.

Thus, you need to use the asynchronous form instead.

```
sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:
```